# how to draw a d3 bar chart for a local geojson file

Tags: d3.js, charts, geojson

i am trying to plot the bar, pie and bubble chart for the following geojson data stored locally in a `myfile.geojson`. Through stack overflow i got to know how to do pie chart. Taking it as a reference i am trying to do the bar chart. I tried but i am not getting it. here is the code of geojson file.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "profit": 326,
        "npa": 174.000000
}
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "profit": 1762,
        "npa": 1683.000000
}
}]
}
```

The code which i tried is in this plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wfAWIQxe1dcDoyauPuI9?p=info)

I am new to d3. Up to my knowledge i tried. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to completely solve but a few suggestions. Hope it helps and others can edit this or contribute better answer.

1. d3.layout.stack() does not have function .sort and has .values
   instead of .value
2. load .geojson file with d3.json
3. you have .append(text) and should be .append("text")
4. if you are just trying to create bar chart, then I don't think stack layout is needed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions sir. I will look on to them.

Answer (score 1):

As Justin pointed out, you have a few flaws in your code provided on plunker. In addition to this, you are not using the D3.js APIs properly. I would recommend to read through them, especially about Scales, Axes and Selections.

The other problem you are facing, is that you need to transform the geojson data to useful flat array format - you should check the both functions `map` (maps a list to list) and `reduce` (maps a list to a value). By using the both functions (also nested) you can easily create nice data sets out of your raw data.

Finally, here is a working example for a bar chart based on your plunker and provided code snippet: http://plnkr.co/edit/eqJ7AkzWpHO4ZQENkXgy?p=preview

The relevant data processing part happens here, where I extract a data array and a labels array out of your geojson file:

```
d3.json("myfile.geojson", function(res) {
  var data = res.features.map(function(d){
    return d.properties.profit;
  });
  var labels = res.features.map(function(d, i){
    return i;
    // return d.properties.nga;
  });

  barchart(500, 500, data, labels);
});
```

The rest of the code is dealing with properly displaying the bars and axes. This code can now be replaced by stacked area chart or pie chart easily.

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what i needed. Thanks for the suggestions i will look on to them. Thanks a lot.